# UIModalPresentationFormSheet dismiss event for Preferences in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, preferences, viewcontroller

I am doing Preferences feature with UIModalPresentationFormSheet with following code in iPad.

```
self.preferencesViewController = [[PreferenceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PreferenceViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.preferencesViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.preferencesViewController animated:YES];
```

When i save preferences and dismiss view controller with

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But my preferences is not change.

i write my check preferences coding in `viewWillAppear` , however viewWillAppear event is not work with `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

I am fine when i use with

```
self.preferencesViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:self.preferencesViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Where can i check event for `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to get information back to a controller that created you, is to use a delegate protocol. Your preferenceViewController should define a delegate protocol, and the presenting controller should set itself as the delegate before it presents the preferences controller. When you initiate the save of the preferences, PreferenceViewController should send it's delegate a message saying that it's finished and should be dismissed. In the implementation of that delegate method in the presenting controller, it can then read the preferences from where you saved them, and dismiss the PreferenceViewController.